# openni.launch creates a different frames tree for the Kinect

Tags: ros, frames, pr2, ros-groovy, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using openni pkg on a PR2 that has a kinect sensor attached and running goovy. I need to be able to transform between the camera frame and the PR2 links.

When I launch openni :

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

A different camera frame tree is created that is not connected to the PR2

I tried changing the camera parameter for the openni_launch to be `head_mount_kinect` but that din't bring the camera tf frames back on the tree.

The only possible solution that I found is to add another fixed frame to tf specifying that the `camera` and the `head_mount_kinect` are the same frame with no translation or rotation between them.

That seems to much of a hack, is there a more elegant solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128216/openni.launch-creates-a-different-frames-tree-for-the-kinect/) by [rleontie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9571/rleontie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should use the openni launch file that shipped with the PR2; I believe it's in /etc/ros/openni_head.launch alongside robot.launch.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rleontie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9571/rleontie/) on 2014-02-11**:
Thanks Austin that worked. I figured also I could use the launch file from the rgbd_assembler: openni_node_new.launch